# Filling field using row value in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I'm making this model that modifies the table that I show:

[MODEL.PNG + TABLE.SHP + TABLE.PNG](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A8uzlyTFFBq0g3fJ3eEcL9ZMC6IG1cDj)

(I'm sending it this way because the network I'm using have limited access and this is my only option)

The next step is selecting the values from "FECHA_2" that are lower than the value in "FECHA_MIN" for later calculate another field

One of the ideas I have is to fill all the Null values in the field "FECHA_MIN" with the only value I have, but I don't know how to do it in ModelBuilder, so I'm looking for a way to solve this or another idea to make the selection.

Answer (score 1):

From ModelBuilder, to change the null values :
Insert >> Iterator >> Field values

Then connect your feature that has null values, change the setting of the iterator to your value for the null value field

Please check the attached image

[image]

[image]

Also, you can do it without iterator, using Calculate field but here you will use python for changing the values, something like:

```
def updateValue(value):
  if value == 'Null':
   return 'yourvalue'
  else: return value

updateValue(!YourColumn_name!)
```

Comment: But in this case would I have to enter the new values of NULL manually? If it is possible I would like the model to do this acutomaticly, because  the model needs to run with other tables that have different values

Comment: So is the value to replace with null is the same (e.g one value for all the nulls)? and would you get this value from another (one table)? or different values from many tables?

Comment: I would have different values from many tables

Comment: I am not sure if you will be able to do that with ModelBuilder for the reason of multi-values from multi-sources and null values in unknown rows